# Comparing percentage with Highstock

Tags: highcharts

Using Highstock percentage to compare the data, if the first data value is zero, the chart is not displayed correctly.

You can see a example here: http://jsfiddle.net/danieltamiosso/USDjC/

```
    series: [{name: 'test', data: [0, 1, 2]}]
```

Any idea?

Comment: Try using `null` instead of `0`

Comment: This just removes the data point all together (which you may not want). I think the source of the problem is a divide by zero when calculating change from `0` to `1`

Answer (score 0):

In case when you have first values as 0, mathematically is has always 0 value, because compared next value is compared with previous.